# Product of sparse matrices by sklearn TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm try to learn Natural Language Processing with Kaggle competetions, 
but I faced a problem (memory error) when I calcurate product of sparse matrices by sklearn TfidfVectorizer.

I executed a code below.

`s1`, `s2`: `pandas.Series` with texts.

Lengths of both of them are 404287.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
vect.fit(pd.concat([s1, s2]))
tfidf_s1 = vect.transform(s1)
tfidf_s2 = vect.transform(s2)

p = tfidf_s1.dot(tfidf_s2.transpose())
```

And then, its output was bellow error message.

---

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      7 tfidf_s1 = vect.transform(s1)
      8 tfidf_s2 = vect.transform(s2)
----> 9 p = tfidf_s1.dot(tfidf_s2.transpose())

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in dot(self, other)
    362 
    363         """
--> 364         return self * other
    365 
    366     def power(self, n, dtype=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    480             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    481                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 482             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    483 
    484         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    509                                     maxval=nnz)
    510         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 511         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    512         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    513 

MemoryError:
```

---

`tfidf_s1.shape` and `tfidf_s2.shape` are (404287, 86152), so `tfidf_s1.dot(tfidf_s2.transpose)` shpae will be (404287, 1).

My memory status is about

- MemTotal:       24570420 kB
- MemFree:        10896612 kB
- MemAvailable:   19635868 kB

So I think memory is plenty enough. Actually `cat /proc/meminfo` while excuting shows no exhausted MemFree.

Would you give me some advises how I can avoid the error or assumption why a memory error occured.

---

My envirionment:

ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

python 3.5.2

numpy==1.15.4

pandas==0.23.4

scipy==1.2.0

scikit-learn==0.20.2

All of them work in docker container.

Answer (score 0):

So 2 sparse matrices of shape `(404287, 86152)`.  The second is transposed

```
(404287, 86152) * (86152, 404287) =>  (404287, 404287)
```

The sparse matrix product is done in two steps.  First looks at the pattern of nonzeros, and determines the shape of the return and the number of nonzeros.  It then allocates such a matrix, and fills it.

The error occurs when allocating the return matrix.

```
  indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
  indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
  data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
  return = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indptr, indices), shape...)
```

Evidently `nnz` is too large; too large a proportion of the very large return matrix will be nonzero.

Why do you think the return shape should be `(404287, 1)`?

Comment: I misunderstood. I need only diagonal components, but dot product doesn't output only diagonal components, of course. I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: So do you think that you're legitimately running into a memory error then? I'm coming across the same error, but trying a series size 1.2m entries... wondering how much memory I need for that matrix.